# What is the status of Beta? How fast is this site growing?

Tags: discussion

I think that ell.stackexchange has the potential to become one of, if not "the" largest stackexchange site.  The need for English language help in the world is ubiquitous.  Is there any indication of growth rate of this stack compared to others?  Is there indication from Stack Exchange llc that they recognize this potential?

Answer (score 11):

I cannot share specific details, but the year-over-year growth rate of English Language Learners is similar to that of English Language & Usage in the year following the public beta of both.

English Language & Usage did have a beta of only 3 months, but it is important to note that Stack Exchange graduated sites much more quickly in 2010 than it does now; we are performing quite well and expect graduation in due course.

I don't believe the company is treating us as special in any particular respect, nor do I think there is any need to. Although there is certainly potential, the site has to live or die on its own merits, and Stack Exchange cannot put undue effort into one site at the expense of others.